# Custom Windows Group (Server 2008 R2) Security Principal

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, user-accounts, settings

What is the easiest way to provision a Windows group on Server 2008 R2 that will allow me to add it to the list of authorized people that can RDP?  Eg when I look at the object types allowed I have options for built-in security principals and users.  How can I enable my group to be added to the RDP access list?

Comment: Also note when you are enabling remote desktop on Windows Server 2008 there is a secure and less secure setting.  If all of your users are Windows 7, maybe Vista also, and up you can select more secure.  If you have people remoting in from Windows XP then you may have to select less secure.  If you select secure then your XP users may not be able to access the server.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what squillman says we usually follow the practice of creating a group at the AD level and adding that group to the Administrators or Remote Desktop Users groups, then adding the users to that AD group.  It prevents having to do user management on every single server and you can tell from a users list of groups which machines he has privileges to.

Comment: Just as Andrew mentioned I prefer to create and manage a group in the AD.  Just add the group the server, the Remote Desktop Group, and everyone in that AD group will be able to remote into the server.  It is quite a bit easier to add people to the AD group vs touching each server you want to modify privileges on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for a single server, add your group as a member of the Remote Desktop Users group on the server.